# innerText shows content but doesn't allow me to change it

Tags: javascript

I have a JS function activating after an onclick event on an A tag. Here is the code :

```
(function(MTM) {
  MTM.selectAllNone = function(e) {
    var string = e.target.textContent || e.srcElement.innerText;
    var list = document.getElementById('my-div');
    var inputs = list.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var length = inputs.length;
    if (string == 'Select all') {
      for (var i=0; i<length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox') {
          inputs[i].setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
        }
      }
      string = 'Select none';
    }
    else {
      for (var i=0; i<length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox') {
          inputs[i].removeAttribute('checked');
        }
      }
      string = 'Select all';
    }
  };
}(window.MTM = window.MTM || {}));
```

And on the A tag, here it goes :

`<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="MTM.selectAllNone(event);">Select all</a>`

Now, while debugging, I can see that "string" contains the text "Select all". It goes well through the `if (string == 'Select all')`. And the line `string = 'Select none';` does change the string variable. But it doesn't change the text of the anchor tag.

Maybe something obvious?

Comment: I am voting for you. It's the most I can do here for you :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var string = e.target.textContent` does not mean that `string` becomes an alias for `e.target.textContent`, it means that the `string` [*points*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computing%29) to the same *value*. When you do `string = "blah"` you are just *pointing* `string` at a different value. You need to point the property `.textContent` of `e.target` at the value new value you want.

```
if (e.target.textContent != null) e.target.textContent = "Select all"
if (e.srcElement.innerText != null) e.srcElement.innerText = "Select all"
```

Comment: I don't get it. Why is `var string = e.target.textContent || e.srcElement.innerText; string = 'Hello';` NOT the same as `e.target.textContent = 'Hello';` ?

Comment: `var string = e.target.textContent` does not mean that `string` becomes an alias for `e.target.textContent`, it means that the `string` [*points*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computing)) to the same *value*. When you do `string = "blah"` you are just *pointing* `string` at a different value. You need to point the property `e.target.textContent` at the value new value you want.

Comment: Oh, I see, I'm stupid. From what I see, there is no way to pass a variable by reference in JS without any kind of hack (using object). Thanks a lot!